# Add opacity mask to Scrollviewer Content without affecting the Scrollbar itself

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I´d like to "fade out" the Content of a Scrollview to the bottom and top of the Scrollview. I´ve done so by adding a Opacity Mask to the View. My problem now is that the Scrollbar itself fades out at the bottom and top aswell.
Is there anyway to work around that?

My Scrollview Code: (Edited the Stackpanel Content)

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,66,460,34">
    <ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                             EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                          Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF000912"
                          Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF000912"
                          Offset="0.9" />
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent"
                          Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Rectangle Height="1500"
                   Width="400"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                   VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- Imagine this Rectangle is a huge pile of content -->
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Can you not set opacity just for the StackPanel?

Comment: Nope already tried that. The problem here is the opacity would just be set for 2 positions of the Stackpanel - the very top + bottom. If I would scroll e.g. to the middle of my content the opacity would not be visible.

Comment: Add an outer StackPanel to the ScrollViewer which will have the margins and opacity set instead of it and put the content StackPanel inside the outer StackPanel.

Comment: As long as i´ve understood you right this way does not work aswell. Putting the (Content) StackPanel inside an other StackPanel with your mentioned dimensions results in the ScrollViewer not registering that there is scrollable content.

Comment: I have posted an example solution using a Border element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an overlaying scrollviewer with the same dimensions and position as the main one:

```
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,66,460,34" Name="ScrollViewerMain">
    <ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF000912" Offset="0.1" />
            <GradientStop Color="#FF000912" Offset="0.9" />
            <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1" />
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </ScrollViewer.OpacityMask>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Rectangle Height="1500" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- Imagine this Rectangle is a huge pile of content -->
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
<ScrollViewer Margin="0,66,460,34" Name="ScrollViewerOverlay" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewerOverlay_ScrollChanged">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Rectangle Height="1500" Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <!-- Keep this Rectangle transparent -->
        </Rectangle>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Then you can bind to the overlaying scrollviewer ScrollChanged event to scroll the main content like this:

```
private void ScrollViewerOverlay_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ScrollViewerMain.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollViewerMain.VerticalOffset + e.VerticalChange);
}
```

Comment: Yep that works but again just for the very top  and bottom of the list. If I scroll a bit the opacity will of cause disappear. [example image](https://picload.org/view/rirpiwia/unbenannt.png.html)

Comment: And this is how it should always [LOOK](https://picload.org/view/rirppgal/unbenannt.png.html) like - but just not applied to the Scrollbar itself